# Getting Regional setting options from code

Tags: vb6, control-panel

I am working on a VB6 application. I need to get the regional settings options like

1. Location information
2. Standards and formats
3. Default input language
4. Language for non-unicode language

Is there any API available for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GetLocaleInfo for this.

I found [this example](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_get_internationalization.html) to be useful.